# Error: An API access token is required to use Mapbox GL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapbox-gl, react-map-gl

I am using react-gl library to use the map-api using mapbox. I have created an account mapbox as well still it is showing the error depicted in the picture.

Here is my code for app.js

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Map from 'react-map-gl';

function App() {
  return (
    <Map
      initialViewState={{
        longitude: -122.4,
        latitude: 37.8,
        zoom: 14
      }}
      mapboxApiAccessToken = {process.env.REACT_APP_MAPBOX}
      style={{width: 600, height: 400}}
      mapStyle="mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9"
    />
  );
}

export default App
```

Here is the error:
[image]

[image: Here is my error in vscode]

Comment: check your mapbox `api token`

Comment: Its correct , I have authenticated it as well!

Comment: check what the value of `mapboxApiAccessToken` is

Comment: what about if you use `mapboxApiAccessToken="{process.env.REACT_APP_MAPBOX}"` - check that `process.env.REACT_APP_MAPBOX` is correct

Comment: Still same issue :(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I faced the same problem. You must to change mapboxApiAccessToken to mapboxAccessToken.

Comment: Thanks Dani , will try for sure!

Answer (score 2):

Big shout out to [Dani Pérez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4912506/dani-p%C3%A9rez). Apparently his answer is correct. Just to add on to his answer, in `react-map-gl v7.0`, they decided to rename various props and one of those props is `mapboxApiAccessToken`

> Renamed props for better consistency with the wrapped library:
>
> - `mapboxApiAccessToken` is now `mapboxAccessToken`

This is mentioned in their **Upgrade guide**:
https://visgl.github.io/react-map-gl/docs/upgrade-guide