# MapboxGL won't work in NodeJS production environment, but works in development

Tags: node.js, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl, react-map-gl

I have this section in `index.js`:

```
<ReactMapGL
    ref={this.map}
    className={classes.root}
    {...viewport}
    width="100%"
    height="100%"
    scrollZoom={isExpanded ? true : false}
    touchAction={isExpanded ? 'pan' : 'pan-y'}
    mapStyle={this.getMapStyle(homicides)}
    interactiveLayerIds={["homicides"]}
    getCursor={this.getCursor}
    onClick={this.handleClick}
    mapboxApiAccessToken={process.env.REACT_APP_MAPBOX_API_ACCESS_TOKEN}
    onViewportChange={onViewportChange}
>
```

My `.env` file has this:

`REACT_APP_MAPBOX_API_ACCESS_TOKEN=pk.my-big-long-mapbox-api-token`

When I run `npm start` on my local computer, which runs Arch Linux, it opens my web browser and navigates to `http://localhost:3000/`, and I can see the map.

But then I moved the project to a remote Arch Linux server. On the remote server, I ran `npm run build`, then `serve -s build`, which told me to go to `http://my-server-ip-address:3000`. I went there, but the map did not show up.

In my browser's development console, I saw this error:

`Uncaught Error: An API access token is required to use Mapbox GL. See https://docs.mapbox.com/api/overview/#access-tokens-and-token-scopes at e.RequestManager._makeAPIURL (mapbox.js:214:23) at e.RequestManager.normalizeSourceURL (mapbox.js:104:21) at R (load_tilejson.js:38:71) at Se.load (vector_tile_source.js:110:33) at Se.onAdd (vector_tile_source.js:146:14) at Jt.addSource (style.js:753:50) at Jt._load (style.js:311:18) at style.js:278:18`

I've run `npm update`.

None of the solutions from these StackOverflow questions have helped me either:

- [How to solve that A valid Mapbox access token is required to use Mapbox GL JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72254578/how-to-solve-that-a-valid-mapbox-access-token-is-required-to-use-mapbox-gl-js)
- [Error: An API access token is required to use Mapbox GL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71612394/error-an-api-access-token-is-required-to-use-mapbox-gl)

I also tried replacing `{process.env.REACT_APP_MAPBOX_API_ACCESS_TOKEN}` with the actual API token's string. It works on my local machine when I run `npm start` but not on my remote server when I run the same command. The map also does not work when I run `npm start` and go to `http://my-server-ip-address:3000`.

**UPDATE**

In my development environment -- my personal computer, which has `nginx` installed -- I ran `npm run build` and navigated my browser to  `http://localhost/my-project/build/`.

When the page loads, I can open my browser's Developer Tools console with Ctrl+Shift+C, navigate to the "Network" section, and see this GET request: `https://api.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.mapbox-streets-v7.json?secure&access_token=MAPBOX_API_ACCESS_TOKEN`.

But when I run `npm run build` in my project's directory, then navigate my browser to `http://my-server-ip-address/my-project/build`, I cannot see any such GET request when in my browser's dev console.

The only Mapbox-related GET request I see is this one: `https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/plugins/mapbox-gl-rtl-text/v0.2.3/mapbox-gl-rtl-text.js`.

Comment: From the docs in the supplied link: "You must supply a valid access token by using the access_token query parameter in every request." Does this react component set that required parameter?

Comment: It is working in development mode on my local machine so I would think so.

Comment: Can you double check? Are there domain restrictions with mapbox?

Comment: @Phix I logged into my Mapbox account and see no URL restrictions on my token.

Comment: Ok, going back to my previous question, did you write this react component that youre passing the API key to? If not, is it old enough to be passing the old query parameter? Do you see network calls to mapbox, if so, does it pass the expected key with the expected param name?

Comment: @Phix updated my original question to answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My development `package.json` had `"react-map-gl": "^4.1.16"`. on production, is a version higher than 7.0.

I deleted `package-lock.json` in the production server then re-ran `npm install` and `npm run build`.